# Combine multiple rows into one row - Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I need help finding a way to combine multiple rows into one row in excel.

For example, I have 8 columns (A - H) of data in rows 1 - 4 and 5 - 8 (Table 1). I need a method to move all columns of rows 2 - 4 to columns I - AF of row 1 and all columns of rows 4 - 8 to columns I - AF of row 5 (Table 2). The resulting blank rows are not necessary either. In reality, I need to apply this method multiple times. Any ideas?

```
Table 1
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
2   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
3   17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
4   25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32
5   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
6   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
7   17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
8   25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32

Table 2
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   …   AD  AE  AF
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   …   30  31  32
2                                                   
3                                                   
4                                                   
5   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   …   30  31  32
6                                                   
7                                                   
8
```

Comment: `Any ideas?` is too broad for this forum.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  Please post any code you have tried and explain specifically what is in error so we can help you overcome that specific error.

Comment: @ScottCraner  - I apologize. I am relatively new to using excel to manipulate large data sets. For future posts, I will post my efforts first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took care to develop a VBA code, I do not know your level in Excel .. I also took care to make the code as simple as possible.
In this code (below) :
Sheets1 is the sheet where the data is presented and read.
Sheet2 is the sheet where the data is written.
RowsColsTransformer() is the procedure to run.

'VBA:

```
Sub RowsColsTransformer()
Dim CurrentLine As Integer
Dim CurrentLine2 As Integer
Dim CurrentCols2 As Integer
Dim Max As Integer

CurrentLine2 = 2
CurrentCols2 = 1
Max = 10 ' -- Number of lines in the sheet where data will be read.
For CurrentLine = 2 To Max
    Sheets(2).Cells(CurrentLine2, CurrentCols2) = Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine, 1)
    CurrentCols2 = CurrentCols2 + 1
    Sheets(2).Cells(CurrentLine2, CurrentCols2) = Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine, 2)
    CurrentCols2 = CurrentCols2 + 1
    Sheets(2).Cells(CurrentLine2, CurrentCols2) = Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine, 3)
    CurrentCols2 = CurrentCols2 + 1
    Sheets(2).Cells(CurrentLine2, CurrentCols2) = Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine, 4)
    CurrentCols2 = CurrentCols2 + 1
    Sheets(2).Cells(CurrentLine2, CurrentCols2) = Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine, 5)
    CurrentCols2 = CurrentCols2 + 1
    Sheets(2).Cells(CurrentLine2, CurrentCols2) = Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine, 6)
    CurrentCols2 = CurrentCols2 + 1
    Sheets(2).Cells(CurrentLine2, CurrentCols2) = Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine, 7)
    CurrentCols2 = CurrentCols2 + 1
    Sheets(2).Cells(CurrentLine2, CurrentCols2) = Sheets(1).Cells(CurrentLine, 8)
    CurrentCols2 = CurrentCols2 + 1
    '-- Reintialize Line and Column
    If CurrentLine Mod 4 = 1 And CurrentLine > 1 Then
        CurrentLine2 = CurrentLine2 + 1
        CurrentCols2 = 1
    End If
Next CurrentLine
End Sub
```

Holp this can help.